# Is it possible to have a full Ubuntu install on a flash drive?

Tags: live-usb

I am trying to make a full Ubuntu install on my 16 GB flash drive. I currently have a persistent Edubuntu 12.04 LTS on it, but this is the install version, which has an annoying "Try Ubuntu" button, as well as a "Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" app in it. Is  this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can install Ubuntu on a USB, but it won't transfer nicely to other systems. I'm running a Lubuntu install from a usb stick right now. Just boot up a installation disc and choose install, then when it comes time to choose the install type pick "something else" and specify that your install be done to the usb stick (eg "/" on "sdb1" use as "ext4"), make sure to specify the bootloader to it as well (eg "sdb"). Ubuntu doesn't care if it's a flash drive, ssd, or hard drive.

To find out the correct device name for you USB drive, you can open a terminal and run

```
lsblk
```

That will list all attached drives, one of which (usually `/dev/sdaX`) is your internal hard drive and one (usually `/dev/sdb1`) will be the pendrive.

Official Ubuntu Installation Instructions (These are for 13.10, but it's the same):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Comment: Why did you say install on sda1? That isn't a flash drive!